# Does Azure Data Lake Store Data for Analytics on temporarily purpose only?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-store

I'm going through a course in MVA "Introducing Azure Data Lake", and till module 2 ,in each vid it's highlighting, that we are paying only for time job is taking to execute.

This get me confused, if its has tendency or meant for storing the data in it permanently  of our all transaction history data or it's  meant for just  analysing the portion of transaction temporarly in it and after doing computation on it with any analytical language i.e. USQL, HIVE ,PIG and drop the temporary analytical source once its done.

In other words:

Is it creating a temporary or staging table  & analysing  data on it and dropping the table after  outcome of stats .
Or
Data lake has tendency or meant to store data for future use like warehouse  and do analytics on it as per business requirement
and  doesn't cost for that storage that much historical that but only for the processing time for analysing on it.

Regards
Harsimran

Comment: Providing my understandings as comments as not entirely sure(would be glad enough if I am corrected) - 
The data is always stored in ADL and in ADLA we create and run jobs. The jobs picks up the data from the ADL (we mention the path of the file from where we need to take the data). Remember they are terming ADLA as `Job as a Service`.

Comment: So it means storage comes with a cost and is ultimately depends how many clusters or space is utilizing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data that you load into the ADL storage account or write with a U-SQL or Hive job (e.g., with an OUTPUT statement or inserting into a table), will be stored in the ADL storage account and will use the space. The space in your ADLS account is not limited by any cluster sizing and will grow as your demand increases.